# Not able to cancel with Cancel button in AsyncTask in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, cancel-button

I have created one AsyncTask.

One progress dialog is created in onPreExecute().
While creating dialog itself cancel button is added to the dialog.
In which task is cancelled.

In onPostExecute(), dialog is dismissed.

Issue:
Point at which we tap on cancel button, and we have already reached in onPostExecute()
Here, we do not enter into Cancel button onclick Listener.

Where as, if it is inBackground(), then it properly enters into onClick Listener of Cancel button.

How to handle on that moment where user clicks on cancel, and user reaches into onPostExecute() and thats why not able to execute onClick listener??

Answer (score 0):

you can check for a `boolean` variable in `onPostExecute` . if its true do your work else exit or return from that code. you can set boolean variable on your `cancel button`.

like

```
boolean canExecute = true;
```

and in `PostExcute` do

```
while(canExecute){}
```

and in cancel button set `canExecute` to `false`;

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not exactly what you describe. (without the code it's not easy... please post some code)

Once you reach the onPostExecute and if the dialog isn't dismiss yet when the user click on Cancel: the cancel listener is executed, but the `asyncTask.cancel(...)` will fail : i.e. it return `false` (since the task is already executed).

If your need is to interrupt the `onPostExecute` code : then move that code in the AsyncTask.doInBackground and keep the code of the button cancel as simple as possible :

```
if(asyncTask.cancel(true)){
    dialog.dismiss();
}else{
    //the asyncTask is already in the onPostExecute
    //the dialog will be dismissed in the onPostExecute... so don't do anything.
}
```

Keep the code of the onPostExecute() as simple as possible :

```
dialog.dismiss();
```